# How to put ArrayDeque in JRI and do some forecast with R

Tags: java, jri, arraydeque

I have a calculator, which I am going to use for some forecast. I have JRI running and the very last thing is to take the data from an ArrayDeque and give it to JRI to its job. I was thinking about something like this, but it's not working:

```
re.eval("datats<-ts("+com.testJRI.ArrayHolder.getArray(Array)+",frequency=365;");
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For all of you, who are going to have the same problem :

```
double [] arrayStr = new double[fr.md.pack.ArrayHolder.getArray(Array).size()];
int count = 0;
for (Iterator<Double> i = fr.md.pack.ArrayHolder.getArray(Array).iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        arrayStr[count++] = i.next();
}

re.assign("data",arrayStr);
```